# Angular routing - how to formulate path?

Tags: angular, typescript

**Goal**: I want the site to be routed to the EN or ES version. More Specifically, if they choose Spanish, it should:

- Go from: http://localhost:4200/en/#/security/login
- To: http://localhost:4200/es/#/security/login

Basically I need localhost:4200/en to go to localhost:4200/es

Or vice versa if they choose English.

*BUT*, I can't hardcode it because the root is different for Dev/Rel/Prod.

**Problem**: It always routes to: http://localhost:4200/en/#/es

**What I've tried**:

When I do:

```
if (event.value == "es") { this.routerService.navigate(['/es/']); }
```

I get:

http://localhost:4200/en/#/es

I get the same result also for:

```
if (event.value == "es") { this.routerService.navigate(['es/']); }
if (event.value == "es") { this.routerService.navigate(['/es']); }
```

**Expected Result**:
http://localhost:4200/es/
**Actual Result**:
http://localhost:4200/en/#/es

Comment: Please can you include your routing file and clarify what are you using for translation?

Comment: The router allows navigating to routes of the application. Not to the URL of a different application. Use a plain old link, of window.location

Comment: I think this   `this.routerService.navigate(['/es']` should work with `router.navigate`. if you are using the `window.location` please try `window.location.href = '/es'`

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan , I tried using window.location.href. I did window.location.href = window.location.hostname + "/es/" . hostname was localhost according to debugger. But it still directed it to: http://localhost:4200/en/localhost/es/

Comment: Please can you try with this `window.location.href = '/es'`

Answer (score 0):

Your routers basepath seems to include `/en`. You have two options.

1) Navigate backwards by using `../` and `relativeTo: this.route` like this:

```
this.routerService.navigate(['../es'], {relativeTo: this.route});
```

You have to inject `route` in the constructor like this

```
constructor(
    private routerService: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute, {
  }
```

2) Remove `/en` from the basepath and use:

```
switch(event.value) {
  case 'es': 
    this.routerService.navigate(['/es']);
    break;
  case 'en':
    this.routerService.navigate(['/en']);
    break;
}
```

Comment: thanks. I tried option 1. I used the ../. For some reason I can only get back to localhost:4200/en/#. So when I use it I get http://localhost:4200/en/#/es still